# FontAwesomeIcon with border style

Tags: reactjs, typescript, font-awesome

Hi there hope someone can help, using fontawesome 6 with typescript e.g

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faClock } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons';
```

then using the icon like so:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClock} fixedWidth />
```

if i try this:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-clock fa-border" fixedWidth />
```

it doesnt match the expected icon props of FontAwesomeIcon

in the documentation it mentions border styles e.g. fa-border-left and fa-border-color.  My question is can i use these with the icon component or do i have to use something like in the example e.g.

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-cutlery"></i>
```

Thanks for the Help !

Comment: have you checked this guide:
https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/style

Comment: yep.  have read that but i cant use icon="style here" as it doesnt conform to the FontAwesomeIconProps and i can seem to figure out the border styling using a non string property there doesn't seem to be icon props for border styles.  I can turn the border on or off but not style it e.g. <FontAwesomeIcon .... border /> but there doesn't seem to be a property for styling

Comment: well you can always inspect element and grab those fontawesome classes and style them in your custom css file.